# Birt Report Line Break in PDF format

Tags: eclipse, pdf, birt

I am using Eclipse BIRT Designer 4.2.2. with Juno, I have a very long line(DataSetRow) which looks very good in html preview but when I convert it to PDF last few words/letters are missing.The way I am using it is as data field in a Grid.

I tired suggested solution from internet/other questions like:

-Choosing Preformatted Text property for white spacing

-Putting row["DATA"] in Dynamic Text.

Unfortunately didn't help, I would be glad for your proposals!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose a master page Landscape and enlarged the grids, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

see birt pdf render options:

```
IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION
IPDFRenderOption.PDF_TEXT_WRAPPING
```

[IPDFRenderOption JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc.isv%2Fengine%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fbirt%2Freport%2Fengine%2Fapi%2FIPDFRenderOption.html)

[IBM Issue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM21361)

Comment: Following worked for me `PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
  options.setOption(PDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION, true);`

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem but after doing like this i solve my problem

```
if (row["comments"]!=null && row["comments"]!=""){
var str = row["comments"];
var test = "";
var count=0;
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
test=test+str[i];
if(str[i] == " "){
count++;
if(count==7){
test=test+"<br/>";
count=0;
}
}
test;
}
}
else{
row["comments"];
}
```

this javascirpt code is implemented in **dynamic text** and it will count no.of spaces in your sentence and if the space count equals 7 means it will do the word wrap

Comment: We have another report when I put the same data column there it works ... no interruptions also looks good in PDF, is there no way to work around without a JS code?

Comment: I chose a master page Landscape and enlarged the grids, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while using Birt 4.9.
I have a fairly long dynamically rendered table with so many groups that I can't set line breaks at design time, but setting the PageBreak option to auto causes an exception when rendering DOCX and PDF. There will be a table on the page that exceeds the page. When using the cursor to select, you can see that the content is there, but the content is not displayed normally.
But when I change the "Layout Preference" option on Report Property Editor from Fixed Layout to Auto Layout, the page wrap function works fine.
[image]